# @Column(unique=true) make this parameter easy to validate like @Size

Tags: hibernate, validation

Is there any way of making `@Column(unique=true)` easy to validate like it works for `@Size`? If the username is not unique I would like to get a message and display it to the user.

```
@Size(min = 3, max = 10, message = "username length should be between {min} and {max}")
@Column(name = "USERNAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 45)
private String username;
```

I validate data this way:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(user);
if (constraintViolations.isEmpty()) {
    model.addUser(user);
} else {
    String message = "";
    for (ConstraintViolation constraintViolation : constraintViolations) {
        message += constraintViolation.getMessage() + "; ";
    }
    messageWindowController.display("Incorrect data", message, 14);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will need to write your custom validator and your own constraint annotation.